# Migrated from Azure SDK 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

I am upgrading the Azure sdk. Having issues with missing references such as TableServiceEntity, TableServiceContext, StorageClient, StorageCredentials, CloudStorageAccount, CloudTableClient etc.

Any pointers to how they have been modified? Not finding any references to this on MSDN or here or google. I wish they released guidelines for these scenarios.

Will really appreciate any sort of help or support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

these TableServiceEntity, TableServiceContext, StorageClient from earlier version before storage 1.8,   please take a look at the sample code http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/ for Azure .NET Storage Client Library 2.x, hope that helps

Comment: It seems to me that this is a comment.